# Why use factory_girl for rails testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot

I am a newbie at rails testing so i want to know the rationale behind using a gem called factory_girl for testing.

Currently i am only using rspecs. My model specs is as follows:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do


  it 'creates user' do
      User.create(email: 'asd@we.com', password: 'asasdasdasd', admin: true, firstname: 'qwe', lastname: 'wer', grade: 5, section: 'w', role: 1)
      expect(User.count).to eq(1)
  end

  it 'should not have password attribute' do

      User.create(email: 'asd@we.com', password: 'asdasdasd', admin: true, firstname: 'qwe', lastname: 'wer', grade: 5, section: 'w', role: 1)
      expect(User.first.attributes).to_not include('password')

  end

  it 'encrypts password' do
      User.create(email: 'asd@we.com', password: 'asdasdasd', admin: true, firstname: 'qwe', lastname: 'wer', grade: 5, section: 'w', role: 1)
      expect(User.first.encrypted_password).to_not eq('asdasdasd')
  end




end
```

In the context of this code, i am expecting a rationale for integrating  factory_girl for testing. Does using factory_girl make this code more concise and clear? What specific problems does factory_girl help solve? I appreciate any insights. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind factories vs. fixtures is that you can create special-purpose models for particular test cases rather than maintaining a stable of them for a variety of purposes.

FactoryGirl and others like it make stamping out arbitrary users pretty easy, like your code could collapse to:

```
it 'users can be created' do
  create(:user)
  expect(User.count).to eq(1)
end
```

Then you can customize that to make an admin, or a user with an invalid password, or whatever you might need for any particular case.

I'm a big fan of factories because even if they can make your tests marginally slower they're self-cleaning, that is the method that makes then, when deleted, no longer makes them. Fixtures often end up filled with bizarre artifacts you're not sure are used, and yet removing them breaks tests due to assertions that expect things to be a particular way.